# How to connect to Oracle database from linux mint terminal?

Tags: oracle, linux-mint

I have oracle database configured at a host and I have host address, username and password which pretty much is everything I need I am sure. I want to export database to a dump file but I don't understand how to connect to the database via terminal. What's the command line for this. 
I am using linux mint.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the Oracle Instant Client tools, here's the [download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) - Look for the [tools package](https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/195000/instantclient-tools-linux.x64-19.5.0.0.0dbru.zip) - And also here are the [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst)